# How do I split a contact form into multiple pages?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a huge form that's way too large for a single page. I would like to split this form up into a few separate pages.  What are my options?

Edit: Still haven't figured out how to do this with Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you build your contact form using the [Webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) over the Contact module. It allows you to have a lot more control and flexibility.

Once you're using this, you need to add 'pagebreak' components each time you'd like to add a new page. [This tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/324779) shows you how to do this.

Comment: This module is currently being ported to Drupal 8, but is not usable yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module. This works for Drupal 7 and 8.

If you use Drush you can use the following command line.

```
drush dl field_group 

drush en -y field_group
```

[image]

Comment: The project page clearly states: "Multipage steps: Note: This is only client side and **removed in drupal 8** version." Also, with Drush you now simply use `drush en -y field_group`, and Drush will automatically download the necessary modules, if they aren't present.